# Variables not initializing within a function

Tags: python

I've been given the task of writing a Roman numeral converter in Python. I'm supposed to use three functions. Here's what I have so far:

```
    ##Get a roman numeral from the user
    # @param userInput the roman numeral given 
    # @return The value to calculateValue
    # pg 252
    def getInput() :
        userInput = input("Please enter a Roman numeral: ")
        storedInput = userInput
        if userInput.islower() :
            userAlphaInput = userInput.upper()
        else :
            userAlphaInput = userInput
        return userAlphaInput, storedInput

    ##Converts the Roman numeral to a number
    # @param Converts Roman numeral
    # @return the number to displayOutput
    #
    def calculateValue() :
        M = 1000
        D = 500
        C = 100
        L = 50
        X = 10
        V = 5
        I = 1
        while userInput == True :
            if userInput[0] >= userInput[1] or len(userInput) == 1 :
                convertedNumber += (userInput[0])
                del userInput[0]
           else :
                convertedNumber += (userInput[1]) - (userInput[0])
                del userInput[0], userInput[1]
        return convertedNumber

    ##Displays the result
    # @param convertedNumber the converted number
    # @return the stored and converted number
    #
    def displayOutput() :
        print( storedInput, "is ", convertedNumber)

    getInput()
    calculateValue()
    displayOutput()
```

But I get the error that userInput is not defined on line 45. I thought that variable would be initialized within the first function. Am I not understanding that correctly? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Which line is "line 45"? Can you provide error with full traceback?

Comment: you're getting your scopes in a twist, i suggest you [read up on them](https://www.python-course.eu/namespaces.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. When you define `userInput`, it's only being defined inside the function `getInput()`.

To solve your problem, define `userInput` and `storedInput` outside of `getInput()`.

See [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) for more.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the edited code above but now I'm getting "In calculateValue while userAlphaInput == True" , name userAlphaInput is not defined, even though it's defined in the function before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
##Get a roman numeral from the user
# @param userInput the roman numeral given
# @return The value to calculateValue
# pg 252
def getInput() :
    userInput = input("Please enter a Roman numeral: ")
    storedInput = userInput
    if userInput.islower() :
        userAlphaInput = userInput.upper()
    else :
        userAlphaInput = userInput
    return userAlphaInput, storedInput

##Converts the Roman numeral to a number
# @param Converts Roman numeral
# @return the number to displayOutput
#
def calculateValue():
    userInput = getInput()
    convertedNumber = 0
    M = 1000
    D = 500
    C = 100
    L = 50
    X = 10
    V = 5
    I = 1
    while userInput == True :
        if userInput[0] >= userInput[1] or len(userInput) == 1 :
            convertedNumber += (userInput[0])
            del userInput[0]
    else :
        convertedNumber += (userInput[1]) - (userInput[0])
        del userInput[0], userInput[1]
    return convertedNumber

##Displays the result
calculateValue()
```

Comment: It springs to life with these tiny additions, see. Enjoy the task.

Comment: That's literally all I needed to know. Thank you very much. I was screwing up on not assigning variables to the result of functions.

Comment: My pleasure. Do not hesitate to mark this as the right answer.